# google cloud sdk c++ client

Tags: sdk, cloud, c++14

When I try to compile this code which is given in README, Getting undefined reference to `google::cloud::storage::v2_18::Client::Client(google::cloud::v2_18::Options)`

I don;t see anywhere the definition of `google::cloud::storage::v2_18::Client` in google cloud sdk c++ code.

Where can I get the library?

```
#include "google/cloud/storage/client.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  namespace gcs = ::google::cloud::storage;

  // Create a client to communicate with Google Cloud Storage. This client
  // uses the default configuration for authentication and project id.
  auto client = gcs::Client();
}
```

tried linking with libgoogle-cloud-storage.so but not working.